# Dropdown on Bootstrap not expanding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Wanted a horizontal menu for my application. Used Bootstrap to create it using the 
this http://www.bootply.com/113314 example. it is not working though. Also need help to understand how the button identifies the appropriate list without specifying id or name anywhere given the fact that there are more than one in the document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div align="center">
        <a href="home.erp">
            <img title="Home" class="img-rounded" src="images/empireSmall.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             Administration
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                <li><a href="karateInvoiceApplication.erp"> Invoice Application</a></li>

                <li><a href="karateStudentApplication.erp"> Karate Student</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             System
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                <li><a href="userApplication.erp"> User Application</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try re-ordering so jQuery is loaded prior to `bootstrap.min.js` - this is a dependency.  Bootstrap knows which dropdown menu to show as the associated button is parented by the same `<div class="btn-group">`.

Comment: Understood. It worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to confirm for anyone else finding the same issue - ensure jQuery is referenced prior to Bootstrap JavaScript (e.g. `bootstrap.min.js`), as this is a dependency.